# When using python networkx is it possible to add multiple labels to a single node (i.e. a main label and then a sub label)?

Tags: python, networkx

When using python networkx is is possible to add multiple labels to a single node (i.e. a main label and then a sub label in each node)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean 'attribute' for 'label', then you can do this in (at least) 2 ways

For example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('Bob', {'age':45, 'gender':'male'})
G.node['Bob']['age']
> 45
G.add_node('Sara', age=40, gender = 'female')
G.node['Sara']['age']
> 40
G.node['Sara']['gender']
> 'female'
```

Notice that in the assignment for `'Sara'` I didn't need to make the attribute names into strings, but when I accessed them, I did.

If on the other hand you mean that you want to have two different names for the node when you reference it, that's a different matter.  For example say you want to use `G.neighbors(node_name)` to access the neighbors of a given node, you won't be able to use `'Robert'` and `'Bob'` interchangeably for the node name (unless there's something I'm unaware of).

Comment: In newer versions of networkx you can't pass a dict anymore

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can be any hashable Python object. You could use a tuple of multiple labels if you want.

From the documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_node.html#networkx.Graph.add_node

A hashable object is one that can be used as a key in a Python dictionary. This includes strings, numbers, tuples of strings and numbers, etc.

On many platforms hashable items also include mutables such as NetworkX Graphs, though one should be careful that the hash doesn’t change on mutables.